# Python regex: removing all special characters and numbers NOT attached to words

Tags: python, regex, special-characters, findall

I am trying to remove all special characters and numbers in python, except numbers that are directly attached to words.

I have succeded in doing this for all cases of special characters and numbers attached and not attached to words, how to do it in such a way that numbers attached are not matched.

Here's what I did:

```
import regex as re
string = "win32 backdoor guid:64664646 DNS-lookup h0lla"
re.findall(r'[^\p{P}\p{S}\s\d]+', string.lower())
```

I get as output

> win backdoor guid DNS lookup h lla

But I want to get:

> win32 backdoor guid DNS lookup h0lla

demo: https://regex101.com/r/x4HrGo/1

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, the above regex you shared won't cover all special characters and it is matching everything including full numbers, numbers standing alone must not be matched. PyPi regex covers those collection {P}. {S}. Normal re doesn't...

Comment: Normal `re` does cover matching just letters and digits. You regex matches just letters and is equal to `[^\W\d_]+`

Comment: You are right. Thanks for that part :)

Comment: I posted the answer with explanations below. Please let know of any corner cases you need to handle.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I noticed it fails when strings are separated by underscore for instance "jsdhsjdhsjdshjds_dkshdskhdsjhds" It won't detect at all

Comment: Yes, I used word boundaries and they prevent from matching when inside underscores. Remove `\b`s if you do not need them, use `r'(?:(?:[^\W\d_]+\d|\d+[^\W\d_])[^\W_]*|[^\W\d_]+)'`. I updated the answer.

Comment: smart. Thank you again!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To match **alphanumeric strings or only letter words** you may use the following pattern with `re`:

```
import re
# ...
re.findall(r'(?:[^\W\d_]+\d|\d+[^\W\d_])[^\W_]*|[^\W\d_]+', text.lower())
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/bssxH8/2).

**Details**

- `(?:[^\W\d_]+\d|\d+[^\W\d_])[^\W_]*`- either 1+ letters followed with a digit, or 1+ digits followed with a letter, and then 0+ letters/digits
- `|`  - or
- `[^\W\d_]+`  - either any 1+ Unicode letters

**NOTE** It is equivalent to [`\d*[^\W\d_][^\W_]*` pattern](https://regex101.com/r/bssxH8/3) [posted by PJProudhon](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58835448/3832970), that matches any 1+ alphanumeric character chunks with at least 1 letter in them.

Answer (score 2):

You could give a try to [`\b\d*[^\W\d_][^\W_]*\b`](https://regex101.com/r/6mwzEy/1)

Decomposition:

```
\b       # word boundary
/d*      # zero or more digits
[^\W\d_] # one alphabetic character
[^\W_]*  # zero or more alphanumeric characters
\b       # word boundary
```

For beginners:

`[^\W]` is typical double negated construct. Here you want to match any character which is not alphanumeric or `_` (`\W` is the negation of `\w`, which matches any alphanumeric character plus `_` - common equivalent `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`).

It reveals useful here to compose:

- Any alphanumeric character = `[^\W_]` matches any character which is not non-[alphanumeric or `_`] and is not `_`.
- Any alphabetic character = `[^\W\d_]` matches any character which is not non-[alphanumeric or `_`] and is not digit (`\d`) and is not `_`.

Some further reading [here](https://www.rexegg.com/regex-interesting-character-classes.html#obnoxious).

---

Edit:
When `_` is also considered a word delimiter, just skip the word boundaries, which toggle on that character, and use `\d*[^\W\d_][^\W_]*`.
Default greediness of star operator will ensure all relevant characters are actually matched.

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/6mwzEy/3).

Comment: Looks good indeed. But it fails for cases with underscore for instance "jhdsjdhs_jdshjdshds" is not matched at all. I would expect "jhdsjdhs" and "jdshjdshds" separately: https://regex101.com/r/6mwzEy/2

Comment: This is one more requirement which you didn't even sampled. Anyway, as already said by @Wiktor, just remove `\b` which toggles on `_` and you're set. I edited my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Try this RegEx instead:

```
([A-Za-z]+(\d)*[A-Za-z]*)
```

You can expand it from here, for example flipping the * and + on the first and last sets to capture string like "win32" and "01ex" equally.

Comment: It won't match words with numbers at the start.

Comment: @tst it would fail in cases like this hfdjfhdj545hj4k5h4jl54hj as it is not returning full match for that string as whole: https://regex101.com/r/x4HrGo/2

Comment: Yes. Though it wasn't clear from your question that you'd be expecting such strings. I tried to keep it as simple as possible for the provided example sentence.